# Debugging with PyCharm and support for bash globbing

Tags: python, pycharm, glob

My Python script is intended to iterate over all files given as arguments with the following usage:

```
usage: make_it_so.py [-h] filename [filename ...]

Make this and that

positional arguments:
  filename

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

To run it I tend to use bash globbing because there are more than one file. Also, I like to stress test any script to ensure it is working properly with folders and files containing white-spaces, like so:

```
user@host:~$ ./make_it_so.py /path\ containing\ whitespaces/*.csv
```

or

```
user@host:~$ ./make_it_so.py '/path containing whitespaces/*.csv'
```

Until now I am programming mainly using a plain text editor and the terminal. But now I would like to use an IDE like PyCharm to debug scripts more comfortably. And here comes my question:

**How to configure a debug configuration** to

- either make use of file glob*bing or
- setting several file path arguments with white-spaces?

(See an example of my debug configuration below.)

[image]

The argument list I get inside my script is not what I expect:

```py
['/path', 'containing', 'whitespaces/*.csv', "'/path", 'containing', 'whitespaces/1st', "file.csv'", '/path\\', 'containing\\', 'whitespaces/2nd', 'file.csv']
```

Instead I would expect:

```py
['/path containing whitespaces/1st file.csv', '/path containing whitespaces/2nd file.csv']
```

I am aware of the fact, that the *parameters* entry field in the debug configuration of PyCharm is not a bash. But I would expect to make it possible to pass arguments containing white-spaces, somehow.—Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If PyCharm is not expanding your globs then it's not running a shell to run your script in, which would be totally understandable. To confirm that is easy, I would simply run it as it is in the debugger, breaking in the script somewhere, then in a new terminal look at the process tree ([pstree](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) is good for that). Find PyCharm, and its children and you will learn quickly whether bash or any other shell lies between it and the python interpreter running your code.

I don't have PyCharm right now to test but one thing I'd try to coax my IDE (I use PyDev) to do that is replace your `/home/user/make_it_so.py` with something like `bash -c "python /home/user/make_it_so.py"`. There's no guarantee that will work (in fact I'm mildly skeptical as PyCharm likely needs to know the path to the source file to debug it).

if that didn't work, I'd try and write a little runner that contains something like:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('bash -c "python /home/user/make_it_so.py"')
```

and run that in the debugger.

Again, I'd be impressed if it worked, but it might. Anyhow, unless a PyCharm pro steps in to help you out here, I hope that this line of thinking is helpful one way or another. Certainly `pstree` can help you understand how PyCharm is running  your script.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the integrated Terminal and execute your make_it_so.py manually.

Comment: Running the script that way, the debugger does not stop at break points, unfortunately.